# What does "cat -A" command option mean in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I'm currently working on a `Unix` box and came across this [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-cat-command-examples/#4) which I found helpful, in order to learn about `cat` command in `Unix`. At the bottom of the page found this line saying: `-A = Equivalent to -vET`

As I'm new into `Unix`, I'm unaware of what does this mean actually? For example lets say I've created a file called `new` using `cat` and then apply this command to the file:
`cat -A new`, I tried this command but an error message comes up saying it's and `illegal option`.

To cut short, wanted to know what does `cat -A` really mean and how does it effect when I apply it to a file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your man page within your system, that is more dependable than any blog post. man cat will show the manual of cat command in Unix systems

Comment: If you're using a Linux system, I'm surprised that `cat -A` gives you an illegal option error. Most Linux systems use GNU coreutils, which does support `cat -A`. (MacOS doesn't.)

Comment: @KeithThompson It's a unix system, which I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: What kind of Unix system? The question is tagged "linux".

Comment: It's Solaris which I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check  your manual page as below and it will list all options avaialable with your command and check is there -A present, if it is not present it is an illegal option.

```
man cat
```

Comment: +1 for use of "man cat" as an answer. Also, getting in the habit of (being able to and) reading the man pages is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It means show ALL.

Basically its a combination of -vET 
 
E : It will display '$' at the end of every line. 
T : It will display tab character as ^I 
v : It will use ^ and M-notation 

^ and M-notation: 
(Display control characters except for LFD(LineFeed or NewLine) and TAB using '^' notation and precede characters that have the high bit set with
'M-')  
M- notation is a way to display high-bit characters as low bit ones by preceding them with M- 
You should read about little-endian and big-endian if you like to know more about M notation.

For example:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tSo8.png

Answer (score 0):

It **displays** non-printing characters

In Mac OS you need to use `-e` flag and

```
-e      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display a dollar sign (`$') at the end of each line.
```